# Batch rename multiple pdf files from an input text

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename

I have multiple pdf file receipt which generated daily then i need to rename this file according to their receipt number after payment made. Instead manually renaming them one by one, im thinking to use a batch script to save time. So everyday will have different receipt number.

My idea is a script that will ask user to enter receipt number. After user enter first receipt number, script then will rename the first pdf file (eg 1st May) next, script will ask for second day receipt number (2nd May) and rename to the second pdf file. The pdf are generated automatically using wkhtmltopdf script daily. There's also possibilities that, that day dont have a receipt (maybe no fine collected) but wkhtmltopdf still save a empty pdf file. so I need to skip this.

UPDATE WORKING CODE BUT ONLY FOR ONE PDF FILE. How about to process next pdf file?

```
@echo off
set /p str= Enter receipt no:
for %%a in ("*.pdf") do (

echo  Preview: %%~na%str%
ren "%%~a" "%%~Na%Str%%%~Xa"
)
PAUSE
```

Im expected something like this

1. Get pdf file name

   01May2019-Fine-CS0000.pdf

   02May2019-Fine-CS0000.pdf

   03May2019-Fine-CS0000.pdf
2. Enter an INPUT2 (contains of 4 numbers) that I want to add in the pdf file name from No 1

   Enter receipt no:5680
3. Then, combined INPUT1 and INPUT2 become new file name.

   01May2019-Fine-CS00005680.pdf
4. LOOP to ask user to enter new receipt number, then this will rename second pdf file and so on.

Note: Each pdf file name contains  format.

Comment: So you want to search for All PDF's and give them the same receipt number, or are you individually searching for something like `*Dec*` and then give them a receipt number? Please be clear so I can help. There needs to be some relation to the PDF file and the receipt number, else it will do the rename for everything.

Comment: Dear @gerhard-barnard ,Thank you for you response. The receipt will be generated daily, so each day will have different receipt number.

Comment: That does not help me, what are the pdf criteria you want to match the receipt number with? all of them?

Comment: Ok, since my pdf file contain date. How about to match with date? So first receipt match with 1stMay for example..and enter second receipt number that will match with 2ndMay

Comment: That won't work, how should script know that it must match receipt 1 with file 13 for instance? That is just to dangerous, you would need to construct a file with receipt numbers in a specific order, then filter your pdf files in a specific order as well and assign the values to match, but you cannot do that if you do not have strict rules to ensure you do not match the incorrect receipt with any of the pdf files.

Comment: I see... Maybe it wont work at all. Thank you so much @Gerhard for your reply. So i'll just stick to manual renaming then.. and that (-3) very discouraging.

Comment: It is mainly -3 because your question is unclear. You should be able to edit your question and give more detail around how you manually do this, how do you know which receipt will fit which pdf, then it might be easier for us to find a solution and your question will not be downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Validate receipt is only digits, set to 1.
set "validate_receipt_is_digits=1"

rem Order by month in name i.e. Jan, Feb ... or order by file date, set to 1.
set "order_by_name=0"

:Main

rem Set pattern to use.
set "pattern=/od *.pdf"

if "%order_by_name%" == "1" set pattern=*Jan*.pdf *Feb*.pdf^
 *Mar*.pdf *Apr*.pdf *May*.pdf *Jun*.pdf *Jul*.pdf^
 *Aug*.pdf *Sep*.pdf *Oct*.pdf *Nov*.pdf *Dec*.pdf

rem Get the mode and name of the folder of the current directory.
if exist receipts.txt (
    set "mode=SemiAuto"
) else set "mode=Manual"

for %%A in ("%cd%") do set "folder=%%~nxA"

echo %mode% mode in folder "%folder%".
echo(

rem Prompt to continue with pdf file renaming.
set "reply=n"
set /p "reply=Start renaming PDF files? [n|y]: "

if /i "%reply%" == "y" (
    echo(
    call :%mode%
)
exit /b 0


:Manual
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b %pattern%') do (
    rem Clear the console screen.
    cls

    rem Preview pdf name.
    echo Name:    %%~nA

    rem Get receipt number.
    set "reply="
    set /p "reply=Enter receipt no: "

    rem Validate the reply is digits.
    if defined reply (
        if "%validate_receipt_is_digits%" == "1" (
            for /f "delims=1234567890" %%B in ("!reply!") do set "reply="
        )
    )

    rem Rename the pdf file if replied with a receipt number.
    if defined reply (
        set "newname=%%~nA!reply!%%~xA"

        echo Rename: "%%~A" "!newname!"
        ren "%%~A" "!newname!"

        echo Status: Reply used.
    ) else (
        echo Status: Skipped.
    )

    echo(

    rem Allow user to see the status.
    pause
)
exit /b 0


:SemiAuto
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "first_receipt="
set "receipt="

(
    for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b %pattern%') do (
        rem Clear the console screen.
        cls

        rem First receipt number.
        if not defined first_receipt (
            set /p "receipt=" <&3
            set "first_receipt=defined"
        )

        rem Preview pdf name and receipt number.
        echo Name:    %%~nA
        echo Receipt: !receipt!

        rem Get receipt number. Space = current receipt number.
        set "reply="
        set /p "reply=Enter receipt no: "
        if "!reply!" == " " set "reply=!receipt!"

        rem Validate the reply is digits.
        if defined reply if not "!reply!" == " " (
            if "%validate_receipt_is_digits%" == "1" (
                for /f "delims=1234567890" %%B in ("!reply!") do set "reply="
            )
        )

        rem Rename the pdf file if replied with a receipt number.
        if defined reply (
            set "newname=%%~nA!reply!%%~xA"

            echo Rename: "%%~A" "!newname!"
            ren "%%~A" "!newname!"

            if "!reply!" == "!receipt!" (
                echo Status: Receipt used.
            ) else (
                echo Status: Reply used.
            )
        ) else (
            echo Status: Skipped.
        )

        rem Get another receipt number if last number was used.
        if "!reply!" == "!receipt!" set /p "receipt=" <&3

        echo(

        rem Allow user to see the status.
        pause
    )
) 3< receipts.txt
exit /b 0
```

This code does 2 modes.
If the file `receipts.txt` exists, SemiAuto mode is used,
else Manual mode is used.

In Manual mode, if the reply is not defined, renaming is skipped.
If the reply is defined, then the PDF file is renamed with the
receipt value.

In SemiAuto mode, if the reply is not defined, renaming is skipped.
If the reply is <kbd>Space</kbd>, the receipt number read from
`receipts.txt` is used to rename the PDF file. If the reply is
other, then that value is used to rename the PDF file.

Sample `receipts.txt` content:

> ```
> 5690
> 5692
> 5789
> 5880
> 5888
> ```

In SemiAuto mode, if `5690` is used on the 1st rename by
entering `5690` or by entering <kbd>Space</kbd>, then `5692`
will be the next receipt number to use, otherwise `5690` is
retained for the 2nd rename, or 3rd rename etc. until it has
been used.

If `validate_receipt_is_digits` is set to `1`, the
only input allowed is if the value is only digits.
The rename will be skipped if the value is not all
digits. Valid digits are any of `1234567890`.

If `order_by_name` is set to `1`, the order of files
found is done by the month in the filename
i.e. `*Jan*.pdf *Feb*.pdf ...`.
This setting does not recognize years. So `01Jan2020`
will come before `01Feb2019`. Since the PDF files are
generated daily, default is set to `0`, so will order
by file date. View `dir /?` about use of `/o` with `d`
which explains the sort order.

Comment: Dear Michael, Thank you so much! Worked like charm!

Comment: Hi, would like to ask if possible to clear red circle area (refer picture link) after one receipt entered? https://i.imgur.com/5OvQKbn.png

Comment: The console text progresses down. To remove that section of text would require something like the `cls` command but only for a section. `cls` will clear the entire console screen. If that is OK, then insert `cls` immediately after both of the lines `for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b %pattern%') do (` on a line of it's own. Doing so, may make the status text not show, though a `pause` could be inserted immediately after the last `echo(` at the end of the for loops. If that is suitable, I could updated the answer.

Comment: I see.. really appreciate if you could help on this. I try my own, based on your reply, not working..haha. Thank you again for helping me on this.

Comment: I added `cls` and `pause` into the answer. You can click on the edited link at center bottom of answer to view the revisions to see the difference.